# Add different WordPress excerpt formats to different templates

Tags: wordpress

I added the following code to my functions.php file in WordPress 6.1.1 to display excerpts.

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 100;
    }
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
    
    
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    return '...';
    }
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

...but I also have a use case to show the full excerpt without a read more link.

On page template 1 I add the below code to display the excerpt:

```
<?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>
```

...and it displays the excerpt as per the functions.php file but how do I create a 2nd excerpt without the read more link and apply it to page template 2?

Is there a parameter I can use within `the_excerpt(parameter);` or can I use something like `wp_trim_excerpt` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_excerpt/ maybe?

I came across the below code that is supposed to do what I want

```
function wpex_get_excerpt( $args = array() ) {

    // Default arguments.
    $defaults = array(
        'post'            => '',
        'length'          => 40,
        'readmore'        => false,
        'readmore_text'   => esc_html__( 'read more', 'text-domain' ),
        'readmore_after'  => '',
        'custom_excerpts' => true,
        'disable_more'    => false,
    );

    // Apply filters to allow child themes mods.
    $args = apply_filters( 'wpex_excerpt_defaults', $defaults );

    // Parse arguments, takes the function arguments and combines them with the defaults.
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    // Apply filters to allow child themes mods.
    $args = apply_filters( 'wpex_excerpt_args', $args );

    // Extract arguments to make it easier to use below.
    extract( $args );

    // Get the current post.
        $post = get_post( $post );

    // Get the current post id.
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    // Check for custom excerpts.
    if ( $custom_excerpts && has_excerpt( $post_id ) ) {
        $output = $post->post_excerpt;
    }

    // No custom excerpt...so lets generate one.
    else {

        // Create the readmore link.
        $readmore_link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $post_id ) ) . '" class="readmore">' . $readmore_text . $readmore_after . '</a>';

        // Check for more tag and return content if it exists.
        if ( ! $disable_more && strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--more-->' ) ) {
            $output = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content( $readmore_text . $readmore_after ) );
        }

        // No more tag defined so generate excerpt using wp_trim_words.
        else {

            // Generate an excerpt from the post content.
            $output = wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content ), $length );

            // Add the readmore text to the excerpt if enabled.
            if ( $readmore ) {

                $output .= apply_filters( 'wpex_readmore_link', $readmore_link );

            }

        }

    }

    // Apply filters and return the excerpt.
    return apply_filters( 'wpex_excerpt', $output );

}
```

Output using:

```
<?php echo wpex_get_excerpt ( $defaults = array(
    'length'          => 40,
    'readmore'        => true,
    'readmore_text'   => esc_html__( 'read more', 'wpex-boutique' ),
    'custom_excerpts' => true,
) ); ?>
```

...but doesn't seem to workas intended. Outputs the excerpt with no link but the args don't see to work when changed.  Would be perfect for my use otherwise. Maybe someone sees how to fix this code?

Thanks

Comment: Put a conditional (`if`) in the `new_excerpt_more` to check for the page template: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/ - something like `if ( is_page_template('page-2.php') { return ''; } return '...'`

Comment: Can I apply that same logic to `single.php` and `page.php` in WP

Comment: Yep, `is_single()` or `is_page()`. Also, that code you found is overkill for what you are trying to do.

Comment: `if (is_singular('post'))` worked for me